# How to combine 2 SQL querys to one result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have recently started using SQL and have a question.

My first query outputs **all products**

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  products;
```

My second query outputs the **out of stock products**

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  products
WHERE
  qty = 0;
```

I want to calculate what percentage of the products are out of stock.

To to this I use this formula:

**percentage = out_of_stock_products * 100 / all_products**

I've tried it with this, but this doesn't worked

```
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    products
  WHERE
    qty = 0;
  ) * 100 / COUNT(*)
FROM
  products;
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh I use Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN qty = 0 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM products
```

The above query uses *conditional aggregation* in order to calculate the number of out of stock products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work for me. Sorry my bad I tagged mysql but i use oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(qty = 0, 1, 0)) * 100 / SUM(1) AS per
FROM
  products;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN qty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) as percent
FROM products;
```